# Reading CSV and returning array

Tags: python, arrays, csv

Taking a video game design course and I've never had to use python before so I am very confused... I am tasked with the following :

read in the CSV file into Python and store its contents as a list of lists
(or 2D list/array). To do so, you will make use of the CSV[1] library.
The reading of the CSV file should be done as its own function - please create a function called readCSV(...)
that takes in the file name as the argument and returns the 2D list.

As mentionned I have no previous coding experience with python. I have managed to do this so far and would greatly appreciate some support.

```
import csv

# reading each row and printing it 
def readCSV(fileName): 
    TwoDimList = []
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in r:


entities = readCSV('entities.csv')              
print(entities)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append each row (which is a list of columns values) to your 2d list and return it in the end:

```
def readCSV(fileName): 
    two_dim_list = []  # snake case ftw (PEP8)
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        # next(r)  # skip header line if necessary
        for row in r:
            two_dim_list.append(row)
    return two_dim_list
```

The short version of that is:

```
def readCSV(fileName): 
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        # next(r)  # skip header line
        return list(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `list` on the reader to get the full 2d list:

```
def read_csv(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return list(csv.reader(f))
```

This works because [`csv.reader` is an iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Answer (score 0):

define a function to read csv and return list, and use it later in the program

```
def readCSVinList(fpath,fname):      
        with open(fpath+fname) as csv_file:        
               csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file)        
         return list(csv_reader)  
f= readCSVinList("A:\\Test\\","test.csv")  
for row in f:  
    print(row)
```